# PHP function suggestion need

Tags: php, html

I am little confused in making one function in my PHP page. Actually I want make one function which can transfer value from Filed A to filed B.
My current code is like below

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
<thead>
  <tr>
     <th>S.No.</th>
    <th>Profile</th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Mobile</th>
<th>Requested Credit</th>
<th>Action</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { ?>
        <?php $s=1; while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $s;?></td>
            <td><img class="img-thumbnail" style="height:50px;width:50px;" src="<?php echo $row['user_image']; ?>" alt="userimg" ></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['mobile']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['request_redeem']; ?></td>
            <td> <button onClick="reply(<?php echo $row['user_id'];?>);" class="btn btn-xs "  type="button" ><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-thumbs-down"> Approve</i></button> </td>
          </tr>
        <?php $s++; } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

**in this request_redeem is value which I want transfer in filed called Credit.** Both filed is in same database table. Can anyone please suggest me what should I do for it ? I am newbie and learning PHP yet...so Please let go my foolish questions if you think. Thanks

Comment: so you want to update the field "Credit" by the "request_redeem" value?

Comment: @Mohammad I want exact it. Thanks

Comment: to do that you need to send q request to the server  via ajax or via a form, then create a query that will update the value of "Credit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `$.ajax` function on click on button.Like this:

```
$.ajax({ url: '/my/site',
         data: {action: 'test'},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
             alert(output);
         }
});
```

Through ajax function on given url, you can create function there and update value in that function and return response that would update value in above view.

Answer (score -1):

Manish has given good example for sending the ajax request . You write a SQL query on the request url to update those values.